# Can't push repo after reset

Tags: git, github

I had 3 commits ahead of the origin master and I read that I should "git reset --hard origin/master". Then I removed the repo from Github. The problem is that if I init now git from the same folder to reupload the repo it doesn't recognize any file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After `git init` you have to add remote url to the git repository as origin, then we have to push the code. Use the following commands for the process

- check the remote url with the following command, to know whether your repository contains remote url

  **git remote -v**
- if you donot find any url then add your remote Url by using follwing command then push the code it will work.

  **git remote add [shortname] [url]**

  here the shortname - origin

  url - your remote url

and check  [this link once](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes)

Answer (score 0):

Have you removed the .git folder, it is what holds the data for syncing with a git repo, from the local directory? If not, "rm -rf .git" (in the desired directory), then "git init".